# What is an Instruction Set Architecture (ISA)

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am trying to find a simple, easy to understand explanation of

`instruction set` and `instruction set architecture` (if there is a difference.) I can only find technical references.

I would appreciate if somebody can help explain in a few paragraphs what it is and its importance to a programmer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my grammar but not sure why the down vote...?

Answer (score -1):

*Instruction Set* would be the repertoire of a particular language.

*Instruction Set Architecture* (ISA) is the way that repertoire is understood.

Let's think of the differences between human and machine using `Assembly Language`.

Machines are known to understand zeros and ones, right? They can understand this process far faster than humans.

Humans use textual representations to represent these zeros and ones. (.ORIG, .FILL, .STRINGZ, .END, etc)

Could you tell me what letter is x61 (hexadecimal)? Probably not. But a machine would understand that x61 is the letter 'a' according to its ISA.

Comment: I think you are confusing ASCII with ISA.

Comment: @MackieMesser: This is a bit old but it would be great if you could share your knowledge if you know what ISA is.

Comment: The ISA is the machine language, the native language of the computer. You can program a computer in many languages, but in the end they all have to be translated to the native machine language of your computer, so that the he can actually execute them. Different computers can run the same unmodified program if they share the same machine language.
The idea that different computers could share the same machine language occured first to Fred Brooks in the 60s. Before that, each computer had it's very own machine language. The most popular ISAs today are x86 and ARM, but there are many others.