# What is instruction set architecture?

Tags: computer-science

I'm reading `Computer Organization and Design, Fifth Edition by Patterson` and I'm confused about a few sentences:

Mainly, what is ISA (instruction set architecture)?

Here are some sentences I am having trouble rectifying:

> Maintaining the instruction set architecture as a constant enables many implementations of that architecture—presumably varying in cost and performance—to run identical software.

and

> The term clock cycles per instruction, which is the average number of clock cycles each instruction takes to execute, is often abbreviated as CPI. Since different instructions may take different amounts of time depending on what they do, CPI is an average of all the instructions executed in the program. CPI provides one way of comparing two different implementations of the same instruction set architecture, since the number of instructions executed for a program will, of course, be the same.

What is an implementation of ISA?

My book's definition:

My book's definition seems lacking... or at least I don't understand what i means:

> the instruction set architecture, or simply architecture, of a computer. The instruction set architecture includes anything programmers need to know to make a binary machine language program work correctly, including instructions, I/O devices, and so on. Typically, the operating system will encapsulate the details of doing I/O, allocating memory, and other low-level system functions so that application programmers do not need to worry about such details. The combination of the basic instruction set and the operating system interface provided for application programmers is called the application binary interface (ABI).

also:

> the instruction set architecture—the interface between the hardware and low-level software. This abstract interface enables many implementations of varying cost and performance to run identical software.

So is ISA some kind of program that translates software into machine level instruction like turning on and off switches? What is ABI?

Comment: There are 3 different questions here and all but ABI are quite complex. You may want to clarify what exactly you want answered. First-party sources for this will provide the most comprehensive answer. I'd recommend looking at a RISC ISA like ARM T32 (Thumb) https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets

Comment: In chapter 4, there is an introduction to the A64 ISA: https://developer.arm.com/docs/den0013/latest/cortex-a-series-programmers-guide-version-40

Comment: there's a similar question yesterday: [What is the definition of instruction set architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57732395/995714). And there are many duplicates: [What is an Instruction Set Architecture (ISA)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21248862/995714), [What is the difference between Instruction Set and Instruction Set Architecture (ISA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43293943/995714). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture

Answer (score 0):

Instruction set architectures are the collections of instructions and corresponding abstract virtual machine these instructions represent. There can be many very different implementations of e.g. random-access memory in hardware which are all accessible using e.g. the same x86 CISC ISA's instructions for accessing RAM. Similarly, the same kind of hardware - e.g. the same RAM - might have identical capabilities exposed by unrelated ISAs, e.g. x86 and MIPS.

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964439/which-combinations-of-operands-are-legal-for-these-x86-64-instructions

Answer (score 0):

The ISA is the description of the commands that a computer responds to, including the types of addressing modes, input and output instructions, and interrupt handling, all in terms of the basic machine instructions that the CPU understands.

The computer manufacturer will also write some code that are basic subroutine calls for writing to disk, reading the keyboard, and the like.  Those subroutines have to be written in a way that uses the knowledge of how the cpu will interact with the disk and other IO.

So to write in assembler you need to know the machine instructions, which is the ISA.  To be able to write a program that does any IO you’ll use the subroutines that the manufacturer provides. The  subroutine APIs and the machine code comprise the ABI.

An example that’s pretty old is the BIOS that used to come on IBM compatible PCs. The way it all worked was a computer vendor would manufacture a computer and would get the OS from a vendor.  The interface was a certain chip architecture, like the 8088, 8086, or 80286, which all had compatible ISAs.  Then the computer vendor write a BIOS that dealt with low level details by abstracting away hardware addresses in the BIOS.  The OS vendor, then, didn’t have to write a different OS for every different combination of disk and serial port configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do a web search for "8051 instruction" set; one of the first few hits is pretty good.  Let's take one instruction:

```
ADD A,R2    0x2A
```

This adds the value in the accumulator with the value in register R2 and stores the result in the accumulator.

The left is the assembly language syntax (assembly language is defined by the assembler, a program that reads it and there is no standard other than perhaps the one used in the processor developers/maintainers documentation, but you can make your own assembly language so long as you get the machine code right.  It isn't a standard) and the right is the machine code.

An implementation of an instruction set architecture is a processor that interprets the instructions and acts on them.  So for this instruction and this whole instruction set you need some logic that has an accumulator register, a set of other general purpose registers and ways to implement each instruction.  CISC like this were likely microcoded for a number of reasons, that opcode would basically address into a table of micro instructions in a rom that would mux in the accumulator to one alu operand and r2 to the other, tell the alu to perform an add, and latch the outputs (result and flags) to their appropriate places, then move on to the next instruction.

Switching to another instruction set this one is thumb a subset of the arm instruction set.

```
   0:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
   2:   1880        adds    r0, r0, r2
   4:   18c0        adds    r0, r0, r3
   6:   1900        adds    r0, r0, r4
   8:   4008        ands    r0, r1
   a:   4010        ands    r0, r2
   c:   4018        ands    r0, r3
   e:   4020        ands    r0, r4
```

This is where the term "encoding" would make sense.  Some of the bits indicate to the processor what instruction each one of these is and other bits indicate the operands.

With the documentation that defines an instruction set architecture you can take 100 engineers and get somewhere between 1 and 100 implementations.  If I were to take 100 programmers and give them the task of taking an image and increasing the red value of each pixel by 1.  You would have a (loose) definition, and I would expect to see 100 different solutions...implementations...

The book you are reading is possibly MIPS related which like a small list of instruction sets has countless implementations.  Computer engineers these days often take a course where they have to implement a mips processor.  Take the tens of thousands or more engineers taking a class across the planet each year and repeat that every semester you can start to grasp how many mips implementations there are just from college students.  The same students in the same class(room) the same semester might be in some way educated to produce similar implementations, more so than others in other schools or perhaps ones using the same text book might have results that look more similar than folks using other text books.  There are a number of hardware description languages not limited to vhdl and verilog that can be used which varies the implementations as well.  Similar to my image manipulation program above, a language was not specified, so some will choose Python, some C, some Java, etc.

Some instruction sets are open to some extent arm before armv4, mips before a certain point risc-v being created to be open, 8051 which was cloned way back when and now we have many clones (that are likely in your current computer as well as many of the computers between yours and mine across the internet, same goes for z80 clones).

AMD vs Intel x86 processors is a simple way to understand two different implementations of the same ISA.

So then what they are trying to convey is that one implementation might take N clocks to perform an add operation, 0x2A, another implementation might take M clocks to perform that operation, and averaging out across all the instructions allows some form of comparison between the implementations.  Its a bit sketchy to think of it that way, but this is a text book not reality.  to get to reality you kind of need to pass through something that covers the basics then if very very lucky you get to see the real world implementations and find out all that is involved in executing an instruction and the notion of clocks and performance.

Those MIPS authors like to drive the ABI themselves and ARM has fallen in line with that, but not as severe.   Think of the ABI as nothing more than take the 8051 if I have a function fun (int a, int b);   one ABI may dictate that the first parameter is passed in r3 and the second in r4 so.  some other ABI for the same ISA may dictate that the first parameter is pushed on the stack then the second after that, so when you enter the function you will see the second parameter then the first on the stack (plus perhaps other ISA specific items used for a call).

We see/saw this with x86 over the years, compiler specific then later someone wrote down some specs then compilers started to conform to it.  And depending on the architecture and spec some have changed over time.  ARM was okay with 32 bit stack alignment then changed to 64 bit later.

If you are a programmer you should be able to take one of the older and/or simpler instruction sets and write a simulator.  Very educational.  Then you can use readily available tools like assemblers or compilers and make programs that you can run on your instruction set simulator.  The compressed risc-v instructions or the arm thumb instructions you could bang out most of a simulator and debug it in a weekend.  A full implementation might take another few days.  I'm thinking armv2/3 or armv4t not armv7.   Then you can use llvm or gnu tools to write programs.  Should beyond a shadow of a doubt cover the topic of what is an ISA and what is an implementation.  Even if you only implement enough instructions to perform a simple loop, a handful of instructions at best.

Answer (score 0):

I would say ISA is a specification of what a processor should implement, and the implementation detail is called Micro-architecture(e.g. Out-of-Order Execution, Superscalar). So, it could be considered as an interface between software developer and the physical implementation.

So, if an ISA includes add instruction, a processor vendor has to implement such an instruction in their own way. ISA specifies many other things like the support of virtual memory, etc.

A well-known example of ISA is x86-64 and its well-known implementations (i.e. micro-architecture) could be found from Intel and AMD, while their implementations differ across generations(e.g. skylake, coffee lake) as well.